# Supporting math markup in GIS SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

A lot of the question and answers that I am interested in would benefit from a TeX-like typesetting capability like they have at [math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tex-math-markup-is-sorely-needed).

Should we get that?

Answer (score 4):

This is a formula [image: formula]

Another formula: [image: another]

Comment: you can use latex and google charts on GIS.SE see Yochai Timmer Answer/Comment  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-stack-overflow-question you pointed too

Comment: Thanks. So this is the Google API approach? Does Mehrad 's answer about latex (said to work on Physics and math SE sites) work here at GIS.SE as well?

Comment: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php is the online editor then use the {} in your editor

Answer (score 3):

MathJax is a *very* heavy dependency so we'd need a lot of evidence that a majority of posts on the site would benefit from Tex/LaTeX support.

Otherwise every page load is slowed for every user, substantially, for not much reason...

Comment: GIS is often about projections and transformations. For example, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/how-to-do-stereographic-projection-conversion-w-r-t-changing-point-of-projecti/6522 or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146264/lambert-conformal-conic-isnt-actually-conformal (and related).

Comment: I've seen other SE sites have adopted MathJax once a list of questions that would benefit from MathJax support is compiled. See, e.g. [here](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/25/5293)

Answer (score 0):

An example of somthing ***MathJax*** can do is shown below:

[image: renderd output from the mathjax]

```
$$ \spadesuit \heartsuit \diamondsuit \clubsuit \qquad \color{red}{\heartsuit} \color{red}{\diamondsuit}  \color{red}{\heartsuit} \color{red}{\diamondsuit}$$
```

Whenever ***MathJax*** is not supported, we can use the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

---

## Example of *foo + bar*

I copied this example from [Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A145982)

```
![foo+bar](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=foo%2bbar)
```

[image: foo+bar]

---

## Example of *\sqrt{foo}*

I copied this example from [Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A145982)

```
![\sqrt{foo}](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Csqrt%7Bfoo%7D)
```

[image: \sqrt{foo}]