# When/If mathematical library will be embedded into GIS Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I was wondering if any mathematical or technical library (e.g. [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/), [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) etc.) would be nested into the GIS Stack Exchange by the developers.

Because of many of us, and I as well are using formulas which are "not that easy" to insert into the question/answer.

Of course, I have seen similar topics, but they are not deeply investigated

- [Entering mathematical formulas in GIS SE?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4162/entering-mathematical-formulas-in-gis-se)
- [Support math markup in GIS SE](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/support-math-markup-in-gis-se)

Comment: I would also like to have technical library for mathematical formula formatting here, but how is this question different from previous ones? The SE team already made it clear it would be on us to provide enough evidence to convince them we are worth the implementation (https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/support-math-markup-in-gis-se). Perhaps you can create a query in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and collect some evidence, then, add it into your question?

Comment: Perhaps you can refer to [the same request on 3D Printing that got accepted recently](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/314) as an example on how to request it properly (in short: provide evidence that it's needed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of ["a lot of evidence that a majority of posts on the site would benefit from Tex/LaTeX support"](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/705/115), and/or user votes, I think there is little chance of this being implemented by the SE developers for GIS SE.

As suggested in comments, to provide evidence you could try using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE), or list some example Q&As ([like 3D Printing SE did](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/can-we-get-mathjax-enabled)).

Alternatively, for the subset of questions that would benefit from a formula being presented, you could use:

- a picture (screenshot) of the formula; or
- the Google API approach illustrated by [@Mapperz's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4163/115) to [Supporting math markup in GIS SE?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618)